# Lagrange Multipliers 26

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Find the points closest and farthest on 4x^2 + 9y^2 = 36 to (1,1).

The systems is

2(x-1) = l (8x)

2(y-1) = l (18y)

4x^2 + 9y^2 -36=0

If I solve for x and y and substitute it into the last equation, I get a quartic equation in terms of lamda. If I solve for lambda in the 2 first equations, I get a cross term xy. How do I solve this?

Comment: Well, not sure you'll like this any better:  rewrite your equations as $x=\frac 1{1-4\lambda},y=\frac 1{1-9\lambda}$.  Substitute back into the constraint and get the quartic $4(1-9\lambda)^2+9(1-4\lambda)^2=36(1-4\lambda)^2(1-9\lambda)^2$.  Easy to solve numerically.  I don't see a simple algebriac way to proceed.

Comment: Are any other techniques available to you? Such as parameterizing the curve?

Answer (score 1):

You have $\lambda = \frac{2y-2}{18y} = \frac{2x-2}{8x}$ so $16xy - 16x = 36xy -36y$ implies $16x + 20xy = 36y$, hence $x = \frac{36y}{16 + 20y}$.

Now plugging into our equation 3, $4(\frac{36y}{16+20y})^2 + 9y^2 = 36 = \frac{5184y^2}{256 + 640y + 400y^2} + 9y^2$, so $ 5184y^2 + 2304y^2 + 5760y^3 + 3600y^4 = 9216 + 23040y + 14400y^2. $

Can you take it from here?